# Why is there no unit for (EM * line-height) or (REM * root line-height)?

Tags: website-design, typography, css, units

This issue has been really vexing me for a while.

Across the web (and in CSS frameworks like Bootstrap), `REM` is commonly used for everything from padding (example: `padding: 2rem;`) to border-radius (example: `border-radius: 1rem;`).

Ok, fine, that's reasonable. But why isn't there also a global unit which includes a `line-height` modifier? Assuming you're using a typical grid that's based on typography, your type *scaling* PLUS your type *leading* is your *true* baseline, and thus it seems like a **FAR** more important unit than just plain `REM`.

For example, say your `REM` is set to 16px, and your body text `line-height` is `1.6`.:

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

This is a relatively common configuration. So why is `REM` (which will typically be interpreted as `16px` in this example) used almost everywhere and not a unit that represents your *actual* grid baseline (which will typically be `25.6px` or 16px * 1.6)?

In other words, why is this standard practice

```
my-padding: {
   padding: 2rem; // typically will be 32px;
}
```

but not this

```
my-padding: {
   padding: 2rlh; // typically will be 51.2px;
}
```

(I realize that `rlh`, or `root line height`, doesn't exist in CSS. My question is *why* doesn't it exist?).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question... You can use rems or any valid CSS unit for line-height too, doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: @Cai I'm not sure what you mean. The problem isn't setting a line height. The problem is that there's no equivalent to `REM` for line height.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, what is an equivalent to rem for line-height? If you use rem to set your line-height then your hypothetical rlh *is* the same as using rem. For example you set `line-height: 2rem;` then `padding: 4rem;` is the same as doing `padding: 2rlh;`

Comment: This should be in Webmasters or the main Stack surely?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft No, it's fine here. There's 236 questions tagged `CSS`.

Comment: @Cai I *think* I understand what you mean. Of course you can set anything manually. But that breaks if your line-height changes. Which is the partially why REM exists to begin with. Actually, I think I'm adding confusion because my question could apply to `EM` as well as `REM`. If I want to set padding relative to a parent's `font-size * line height`, there is no unit for that besides hard coding the values.

Comment: @yourfriendzak Nothing would break if you're using REM. The issue is using unitless line-height, which is recommended *unless you want a consistent baseline grid*, which is what you're talking about right? In that case, you set your line-height with REM, and your REMs will be relative to your baseline as well.

Comment: The problem with unitless line-height is that it's relative to the font-size, so what you're proposing is a relative unit of a relative unit

Comment: @Cai Hmmm, that's interesting. I hadn't considered that. I'm gonna have to rethink my premise. Thanks for the thoughtful responses.

Comment: specifying line-height without a unit means "ems." So 1.2 line height = 1.2em

Comment: The stock answer to "Why does CSS lack this setting that is common to graphic designers and typesetting" is because "the CSS standards group lacks graphic designers and typesetters"

Comment: That said...this is a bit confusing of a question. What is your ultimate goal? I believe REM already is exactly what you want. "Line Height" + "Leading"  = whatever REM you want.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because it is too specific to warrant the cost.

In your specific case of wanting to use root `line-height`, the answer is also that most of the time the `line-height` is based on the `font-size` (it is by default), so it'd be useless since we already have `rem`.

---

More generally, we can ask ourselves: "What if I want to use the root's `margin-top` as a spacing for the rest of my margins and padding? Why isn't there a `rmt` unit for that?" and do this for any property. We quickly see that it's silly to have units for every property. `em` and `rem` were chosen based on the `font-size` because it provides a good base for other properties to be styled off of.

With that being said, if you want to use the line height (or any other value) in other property's values, you can use either CSS's [custom properties (essentially variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) or use a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update the answer.
CSS now provides the `lh` and `rlh` units.
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#font-relative-lengths

Comment: Keep in mind [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=lh%20unit) for this. At the moment, it's not supported or planned to be supported by every major browser (Firefox is missing)

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention that. Just that the spec does now cover them. So, indeed, you need to check if your browser support requirements will allow you to use them.